# Prove that two matrices commute iff the square of the matrices commute

Tags: matrices

In my textbook there is a task in which I have to prove the relation
\begin{equation}
AB=BA\Leftrightarrow A^2B^2=B^2A^2.
\end{equation}
For ($\Rightarrow$) it is easy
\begin{equation}
AB=BA\Rightarrow (AB)^2=(BA)^2\Rightarrow ABAB=BABA\Rightarrow BBAA=AABB.
\end{equation}
But how do I prove ($\Leftarrow$)?

Comment: How did you reach the last implication in $\rightarrow$?

Comment: Using the fact that $AB=BA$.

Comment: No. Switching $AB$ to $BA$ in the equations gives you: $ABBA=BAAB$. This is not what you want to show.

Comment: @AspiringMat: $ABAB = A(BA)B = A(AB)B = AABB$. Similar for the other side of the equation.

Comment: Left hand side: $ABAB=AABB$. Right hand side: $BABA=BBAA$. I realize maybe I should have written the last equality as $AABB=BBAA$for clarity.

Comment: Ohh that makes more sense now, I was confused because I was trying to relate the first with $A^2B^2$  which wasn't working. But I also noticed that Dominik gave a counter example below.

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: The backward implication is true when both $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, but false in general.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The equivalence is incorrect. Take for example
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention $A,B$ are assumed to be invertible!

Comment: I adapted the example, it still doesn't hold.

Comment: Note that you could prove this without any explicit matrices using a division ring you know could be represented as matrices - think quaternion units.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: That wasn't my intent; rather I just thought it provides a more intuitive view of why the claim is wrong, if you've encountered the quaternions.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I *totally* just learned something from R's comment! Glad he posted it.

Comment: @R. I suggest posting that as a standalone answer since it is very interesting and valuable. You might add a phrase like "If you have knowledge of ... " or "an alternate proof..." to keep people like TheGreatDuck from complaining.

Comment: @djechlin: Done!

Answer (score 13):

If you're familiar with the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), and the fact that they have [matrix representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations), one easy way to see that the reverse implication is false is to consider the fact that

$$i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$$

(and thus the squares of the quaternion units commute) but that $i$, $j$, and $k$ themselves don't commute. These non-/commutativity relations will carry over to any matrix representation.

Answer (score 2):

The implication '$\Leftarrow$' is so obviously false it surprises me that one should even ask this question. Though commutation of matrices can arise in many ways, one of the most simple ways is when one of the matrices is a scalar matrix (multiple of the identity). So if '$\Leftarrow$' were true, it would mean at least that whenever $A^2$ is a scalar matrix then $A$ commutes with every other matrix $B$; this clearly cannot be true.

There is a multitude of kinds of matrices whose square is scalar without any reason for the matrix itself to commute with all other matrices: the matrix of any reflection operation ($A^2=I$), that of a rotation by a quarter turn $(A^2=-I$), or a nilpotent matrix of index$~2$ (i.e., $A\neq0$ but $A^2=0$). These give many choices for a counterexample. (In fact the only way $A$ can commute with all other matrices is for $A$ to be scalar itself, but you don't need to know this fact to find counterexamples to '$\Leftarrow$'.)

Comment: OK, so I've earned a downvote. I know it is useless to ask why, but let me guess it is because of my opening phrase, which may seem insufficiently polite towards OP. I do not mean put into question the merits of OP, of which frankly I am totally ignorant. What I do mean to say is that when one asks a question one should stop to think about the implications of what one is asking. OP claims this was written in a textbook; given the upvotes on the (unanswered) comment asking which, I think I'm not alone in doubting this was genuinely stated like this (without additional hypotheses) in a textbook.

Comment: Then to be specific, it is obviously false to someone writing a textbook. It may not be obviously false to someone reading a textbook :-)